# Macro for jinja statement does not compile in DBT project

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am trying to create a function that will template jinja for me. The jinja statement I want to use as a function is the below.

`{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}`

I created a macro in *macros/macros.sql* but it will not compile and produces an error. When I check the compiled sql, the select statement was not produced at all, so I can't see what it compiled to. It just shows what was there before I added the select statement as if the code was never added. Any idea of what is going on and how to fix this to work?

```
{% macro listify(loop) %}
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

usage in model1:

```
select 
{% for col in var('my_cols') %}
    nullif({{col}}, ""){{ listify(loop) }}
{% endfor %}
from {{ source('my_source', 'my_table') }}
```

Comment: The error does not seem related to the macro. It says that `model14` does not exist when calling it from `model15`

Comment: I think you are right about that. I removed the error from the question because it turns out it was a different issue. The model name was changed so the other models weren't being created because of the name change.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out! Turns out there were other errors that needed to be addressed before it would compile. I can see the results of the compiled code now. The macro works fine!